# Создание динамических вкладок на Wordpress с использованием Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Вопрос состоит в том, что мне нужно создать динамические вкладки со сменой их позиции при нажатии. Возможно есть скрипт который поможет реализовать динамику?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h2vu4HR48YZfMPEFygPwn7yMj3-ATNOW/view?usp=drive_link
По этой ссылке сам пример того, что мне нужно сделать
Я пробовал создать с помощью виджета "вкладки" но в конечном итоге выходит не то что нужно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: С довольно высокой вероятностью, Вам придется писать свой виджет.

Answer (score 0):

Ни как. Это не типический функционал для `Elementor` Вам стоит создать кастомный виджет под данный элемент. Можно при помощи этого плагина [Unlimited Element Widget Creator](https://unlimited-elements.com/docs-category/widget-creator/) По сути делаете на JS/CSS после инициализуриете.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.